# Can a constant be optimized away

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, one-definition-rule

If we have a `static const` class member the address of which is never used, can the member be optimized away and allocated no storage ?

Comment: Judging by what g++ [output](https://godbolt.org/z/djazEq), I'm going to assume yes.

Comment: If removing something doesn't alter the behaviour of the program the answer is usually "yes".

Comment: A constant that is never used can be *optimized away*.  In another view, since it is not used, it won't show up in the code.

Comment: @ChrisMM The question is asking about `static const` **class member**s -- the example you demonstrate is for constants with `static` declaring internal linkage -- which is different for the optimizer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: "not odr-used" != "not used".

Comment: @Human-Compiler, you're right, I missed the 'class' in the question. Seems then it depends on [how they're defined](https://godbolt.org/z/zns8hT) (for g++ at least)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: With as-if rule, I would say yes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: There are two answers to this question. If either of them answer it to your satisfaction, please remember to select an answer as correct, or leave feedback as to how the answers may be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, but only link-time optimisation is capable of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010455/4386278), because [only the link stage can *prove* that the address is never taken throughout the whole program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1229542/4386278). And, if you're producing a shared library, that's just off the table. Speaking generally, you're best off assuming that the object probably *will* take up space in your executable.

Regardless of whether storage is provided, though, you can certainly expect the compiler to "inline" use of the value, if the initialiser is visible in the same translation unit. You can observe this by failing to provide a separate definition, then doing anything that doesn't involve ODR-use and noticing that you may not get an undefined reference link error.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is *it depends on context*.

The compiler must follow the as-if rule, which ensures that the program must behave the same way optimized as it would unoptimized -- so it can only remove constants that it knows will not affect the behavior of syntactically valid code.

### Short Version

The short version is that constants can only be optimized out if they fit the following criteria:

- Constants are trivial, or have visible constructors / destructors that *do not affect external state*,

  - This effect is transitive. If a constructor / destructor calls a non-visible function, the compiler must assume that the call may alter external state, and is thus significant.
- Constants are not ODR used, and
- Constants are either anonymously defined (in an unnamed namespace), or inline defined

### Long Version

There are several cases that will affect storage backing

1. Whether the constant has been given explicit storage backing,
2. Whether the constant exists in an unnamed namespace,
3. Whether the constant has non-trivial, **non visible** constructors/destructors,
4. Whether the constant is defined `inline` (C++17),
5. Whether the constant is defined `inline` (C++17) and ODR used,
6. Whether the constant is defined in-line, but not given storage-backing

Lets break down these different sections:

#### 1. Constant is given explicit storage backing

If you define storage backing from the start, e.g.:

```cpp
struct example {
    static const int value;
}; 
const int example::value = 5;
```

Then there will usually be storage backing, since the compiler has to assume it will be ODR-used eventually -- even if the constant is private.

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7Ez4vr)

#### 2. Constant is in an unnamed namespace

However, if these types are defined in an unnamed namespace, which makes them anonymous symbols for the translation unit -- then lack-of-use may result in it being optimized away:

```cpp
namespace {
    struct example {
        static const int value;
    }; 
    const int example::value = 5;
}
```

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/86P97e).

This will only work for trivial constructors / destructors, or constructors / destructors that the compiler can currently see in order to optimize out instructions.

#### 3. Constant is in an unnamed namespace *with non-trivial constructor / destructor*

If the constant above has a non-trivial constructor or destructor, or a constructor/destructor that is not visible, the constants will have to be emitted:

Either:

```cpp
namespace {
struct actor{ 
    actor();  // not defined
    ~actor(); // not defined
};

class example {
    static const actor value;
};
const actor example::value{};
}
```

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/j9YfTq)

or:

```cpp
extern int some_global;
namespace {
struct actor{ 
    actor(){ ::some_global = 5;} 
    ~actor(){ ::some_global = 10;}
};

class example {
    static const actor value;
};
const actor example::value{};
}
```

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/q4aTxK)

#### 4. Constant is defined `inline` (C++17)

If you define an `inline static const` or `inline static constexpr` value in C++17, then it depends on whether it is ODR-used for whether the symbol will ever be emitted.

**No ODR-use -- No emission:**

```cpp
struct example {
    inline static const int value = 5;
};

void test()
{
    std::printf("%d", example::value);
}
```

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TTvsfc).

#### 5. Constant is defined `inline` (C++17) with ODR use

If the symbol is `inline` but is ODR used, the storage backing must be emitted.

**ODR use -- Emission:**

```cpp
struct example {
    inline static const int value = 5;
};

void consume(const int&);

void test()
{
    consume(example::value)
}
```

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/v3v1nx).

#### 6. Constant is defined in-line, but not given storage-backing

In the case that you have an inline definition of a static `const` object (without C++17's `inline`), there should never be storage backing. The constants can only be created by constant expressions (with or without `constexpr`), but have no explicitly stated storage-backing -- meaning that they cannot be ODR-used unless declared `inline`.

This is what is leveraged by C++'s type-traits, since they do not produce any additional code since they amount to compile-time constant objects.

```cpp
struct example {
    static const int value = 5;
};
```

[Example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Ma4M83)

---

**Edit:** One more note that I wanted to add: If there is any storage-backing specified to a symbol with non-internal linkage, either through explicit definitions or via ODR use with an `inline` symbol, the compiler/linker *should not be able to optimize this backing out*. At least, not from a proper interpretation of the as-if rule (though certain non-standard optimization flags may permit this).

The issue is that the compiler *must assume* that symbols with external linkage may still be named or referenced elsewhere, even if the symbol is `private` and never accessible via `friend`-ship. C++ has sharp corners where you can [reference private members in template parameters via explicit template specializations](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html). So even though it should logically not be accessible, it actually is from the language (and thus, compiler's) view.

Comment: Ouch ! Thanks for the extensive discussion.

Comment: Oh I forgot about `static const inline`